Why isn't "meanwhile" advisable in this sentence? Doesn't it mean "at the same time"?
I wrote this sentence in another post of mine, and some advised me not to use meanwhile in this case. Why? Doesn't meanwhile mean at the same time?

Education expenditure was highest in India at 15%, followed by 13% in Thailand. Meanwhile, the figures for the remaining countries were around 7%.


The literal sense at the same time wouldn't really add anything in your context, but by extension it often has the sense on the other hand, by contrast, and yet,... which "kinda" makes sense. There's a significant contrast between the average of the top two being twice that of the rest. But I see you've changed the numbers from your previous post, so it now does make more sense to contrast them in this way. Whatever - it's all inconclusive "writing advice" at this level.

Does this answer your question? How to use "average" as a verb?

The "meanwhile" comments were in response to my post, not to the answer, but the link keeps directing the screen to the answer. How can I fix the link to make it work?

@FumbleFingers that's my own post, so no it doesn't. I did ask them why meanwhile wasn't good, but no one answered, so I had to post a new question.

@FumbleFingers The literal sense wouldn't add anything in my context, but I think it helped me link the two sentences. For example in the sentence: I don't like ice cream and I don't like candies, and also doesn't add anything new and is simply used to link the two clauses. I could have just used a period instead of "and". So, I still haven't got it. Isn't linking an important role?

Also, @TimR said that meanwhile wasn't good after I'd edited the statistics.

@Mari-LouA Thanks, I've fixed them all. By the way, do you have any idea why my post was downvoted? I don't mind the downvote; I just don't want to ask a bad question.

People downvote questions for lack of research, effort, sources, references, because it's been asked before, because the answers are useful only to the asker, or simply because they don't like the question. Sometimes a user could be having a bad day, and be resentful that their own answer/question was downvoted. Take your pick :) One DV is not such a big deal.

I think this issue was answered by the previous question, albeit only in comments. First, Lambie said rather than meanwhile, use: In contrast, which I immediately followed with I wouldn't include either meanwhile or by/in contrast (because imho no useful point wa being made by contrasting the first two figures against the average of all others). Then ohshitgorillas said I agree with FumbleFingers about not including "meanwhile", a semicolon might do in its place... (excellent suggestion, that you could usefully have taken on board)....

..that's quite a few comments all revolving around the fact that in your context, meanwhile does in fact mean by/in contrast. After which TimR posted the comment What is the percentage of? GDP? Also, "meanwhile" is not good. And yet after all that you've posted another question here about exactly the same context, and you're still asking Doesn't meanwhile mean at the same time? To which the answer is Yes - but only because at the same time can also mean by contrast (it doesn't always carry the literal sense of simultaneously).

Note that as Lambie correctly pointed out All your sentences are grammatically and semantically fine. But that's several people saying that stylistically we don't think much of including the word meanwhile.

"Whatever - it's all inconclusive "writing advice" at this level." very well said by @FumbleFingers

I think more than "style" is involved.  Register is involved.  There's more to the deft use of language than mastering the nuts and bolts of grammar.

If time were relevant, then "meanwhile" would make sense. "Between 2016 and 2019, GDP in India increased by 20%. Meanwhile, in Thailand, ...". In this example, "meanwhile" is telling you something. In your example, it's just padding.

TLDR literally correct but may have connotations you might not want to convey.

“Meanwhile” is a filler-word here
The use of “Meanwhile” doesn’t add anything to the sentence: it means “at the same time”, but when comparing figures from a single report like this it is a given that they come from the same data-set and are thus for the same period of time. Rewrite the two sentence without “meanwhile”, and you lose nothing:

Education expenditure was highest in India at 15%, followed by 13% in
Thailand. The figures for the remaining countries were around 7%.

If you have a point to make, make it
The previous text is quite neutral: it presents the information but doesn’t guide the reader toward the point you wish to convey. If the interesting point was that India/Thailand spend far more on education than their peers, then be more explicit:

Education expenditure was highest in India at 15%, followed by 13% in
Thailand. In contrast, the figures for the remaining countries were around 7%.

Better yet, tie these together in one sentence:

Education expenditure was highest in India at 15%, followed by 13% in
Thailand - far more than the average for the remaining countries, which was 7%.

I’m assuming the 7% is an average, but that brings up another point...
Avoid vague terms. If you are reporting figures, be precise
What does “around 7%” mean?  Is this an average of the remaining countries’ figures?  If one was 12%, one 7% and another 2%, you’d still get an average of 7%, but that would undermine what I assume your point is: that Thailand and India spend much more than their peers.  Or does it mean that the rest of the countries’s expenditure figures clustered around 7% (still an average, but lower deviation)?
If you’re trying to say that Thailand and India’s spending is far higher than that of the rest of their peers, then choose the highest of the peers, and re-write to say so.

Education expenditure was highest in India at 15%, followed by 13% in
Thailand. None of the remaining countries spent more than 7.5%

(assuming that 7.5% was the highest of the other nations’ spending)

This is really eye-opening. I've seen essay samples where the authors wrote in these ways before but I didn't follow them because somehow, I always felt like I needed to link my sentences with adverbs such as meanwhile, similarly, conversely,.... It turns out I don't need to. Thanks a lot for the tips.

@AnIELTSLearner What you describe is French style.

meanwhile is a rather simplistic narrative segue. It is used to say that one action was happening at the same time as another.

The Lollipop Gang were sitting in the corner of the seedy bar, plotting their next heist. Meanwhile,  back at headquarters, Sergeant Smithers was looking for a pattern in their five previous robberies.

But it isn't only the register that is inappropriate for a dry discussion of expenditures on education; the main objection is that the percentages are  not happening in time but are the result of a retrospective analysis. There is no "while".
Someone may counter this objection by saying that  meanwhile there is just a way of saying "If we turn our attention to the remaining countries".  But you don't need to use a segue with something that isn't going to be a new focus of discussion, something that was tacked on as an afterthought merely for the sake of not ignoring it entirely:

Meanwhile, the figures for the remaining countries were around 7%.
The remaining countries spent around 7%.

Better than a clumsy segue would be to replace remaining with a descriptive phrase that  characterizes  these remaining countries that spend relatively little on education, perhaps something about the size of their populations or the makeup of their GDP.

The user's name is An IELTS Learner, the IELTS is an exam, and the first writing task is to look at a graph, sometimes two, containing statistics, numbers, percentages etc. Candidates have to compare the data, identify the most striking differences and write a summary in 150 words. They have 20 minutes to do this. They must not offer explanations; it's an English language exam, the focus is on language, grammar and the presentation.

@Mari-LouA   This is not an exam prep site. It's a site about learning English. That said, I don't think the advice I've given is irrelevant in an exam context.

@Mari-LouA: You say They must not offer explanations. But surely OP including the word meanwhile there represents unwanted "interpretation". My objection to it in the first place was that it didn't reference two assertions that could meaningfully be contrasted. But it now seems that even if any such contrast could reasonably have been made, it wasn't properly within the remit of what was expected (a summary of the data, not an interpretation).

Thank you all for "going all out" (quoted to show uncertainty of usage) to explain it to me. I finally got what you all meant.

I like the option of just dropping the "meanwhile".  It doesn't seem to be doing anything useful here, at least not in the kind of context that I infer from the sentences overall.  Perhaps "remaining" could be elaborated, as this answer suggests, but would be nice and tight standing on its own.  Only if I wanted to highlight some particular distinction between the remaining countries and the two designated by name would I consider such an elaboration.

@TimR I can't support this answer.  Hard facts, (1) in the original example sentence, "meanwhile" is absolutely correct in all ways, as the sentence is "time-based", the sentence does literally mean meanwhile; it's not even that meanwhile is being used in the figurative sense, which brings us to point (2) even if used figuratively (see more in point 3), it is incredibly common to use meanwhile in such sentences, it's so common it's beyond "idiomatic", it's just normal usage. Sure, I'm still telling people YOU ARE NOT USING APOCRYPHAL PROPERLY but eventually it is "correct". Point (3),

you mention simplistic and clumsy regarding this usage. On the contrary, I find it to be rather knowing, sly, and to put it more cheaply a sophisticatedly smart-ass mode. (So, you've been trading bitcoin and gamestop 9 hours a day for two years and you're up ten percent, meanwhile all my gold is up 350%.) Churchill used this in writing, for example.

@Fattie  Your context isn't comparable. "You've been trading..."    Compare: By the end of the 1964 season, the Phillies had hit a total of 347 home-runs. Meanwhile, the Pirates hit only 104. [fictitious numbers, BTW]

meanwhile doesn't couple well with a context that doesn't involve unfolding events but is a retrospective recap and analysis.

The OED lists 8 meanings for "meanwhile" one of which is obsolete. I don't have access to the OED, it's behind a paywall, but I know you do. Could you please list the remaining seven different meanings of "meanwhile"? Admittedly it may not have been the best choice, but it was hardly egregious and I use it myself in place of "on the other hand".

@Mari-LouA I don't have access to the paywalled OED.  But this is not a question that you can answer simply by consulting a definition. It has to do with aspect.  meanwhile is a segue from one set of unfolding events to another set of unfolding events that are happening (or were happening)  simultaneously with the first set of events. If you establish a context using, say, the past perfect, which is not about unfolding events but about events that have completed,  there is nothing to be simultaneous with.  Hence my example of the 1964 baseball season homerun totals after the season.

OED says that "meanwhile" has seven different meanings. You are focusing on one of the seven meanings. I don't have access to the online dictionary, its subscription fee is too steep for my pockets but there are many users who have free access. I thought you were among the lucky ones but I see I was wrong.

You will hear some native speakers of AmE (who would probably do very poorly on the IELTS exam) saying things like She likes chocolate. Meanwhile, I like vanilla,  where the intended meaning is "on the other hand"  or "but".  It is a non-standard usage.

For example: She liked wearing the skirt suit. Meanwhile, I like wearing comfortable pants, and have loved these past few years being behind the camera.

@TimR (sorry, didn't understand the Phillies example).  no need to labour the point, but I can only say IMO it seems completely common that people use "meanwhile" even where it is as completely non-literal as "on the other hand".  Hence, in last-word summary you say meanwhile is a segue ... that are happening (or were happening) simultaneously .... I'm afraid I simply totally disagree, it's now just used as idiom, interchangeable with any other filler such as "on the other hand".  I do understand all that you've said and I am pondering it. Respect.

(I always get pissed off by erudite people disagreeing with me :/ ). (So I'll go drink.)

@Fattie:  That "on the other hand" usage is a colloquial usage and is in a "chatty" register, which makes it unsuitable for any piece of writing that needs to be in a neutral or formal register.

This is giving me flashbacks listening to comic book records.... The villain has Lois Lane tied to the train tracks. OH, NO! Meanwhile, Clark Kent enjoys a cup of tea on the other side of town. (queue Batman segue sound clip) "In contrast to aspects previously mentioned." "During the time that something is happening, often specifically in a different place." https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meanwhile - it's either a segue, or it sets up a jab at whatever country gets mentioned next that doesn't spend enough on their schools... or does, but are all still idiots.

Cutting the crap, this answer highlights "happening at the same time" (as distinct from "data collected at the same time"). It's the "happening" (over some period) which is significant.

Speaking as someone who grew up in America and has been speaking English for 60 years ... I don't see anything wrong with the use of "meanwhile" here. It makes perfect sense in context. You'd have to ask the person or people who objected what they saw wrong with it. I'm guessing their objection is something very subjective.

Well, I've summarised the comment-based objections from four of us on the previous question regarding the word meanwhile. Nobody suggested it was "incorrect"; we just thought (possibly for different reasons) that it was stylistically weak. It seemed that the OP didn't understand, but since that wasn't the primary focus of the question it wasn't important. We all gave at least some indication of why we didn't like the usage in the exact context, and @TimR has gone much further in an actual answer here. But it's all just stylistic choice and preference, not really important.

In a word, Jay is correct.  Quite simply the sentence is wholly correct. End of story, OP.  The person who advised you not to use it is both naive and wrong. Of course, obviously, every word choice carries massive character traits of the user; for me using "meanwhile" as in the example is rather, oh, "political" sounding, a little "aggressive", "insider", "knowledgeable".  But that is by the by, the sentence is not only correrct, but moreover the most common way.

@Fattie: The reason you think meanwhile is "aggressive", "insider", "knowledgeable" is precisely because when used in the on the other hand rather than the at the same time,  it often carries the strong implication that there is a contrast, but morally there shouldn't be. We never saw the chart that OP's sentence was supposed to be succinctly summarizing, and the figures originally quoted looked implausible to me, but my thinking was Castigating "the remaining countries" for spending less than India and Thailand on education is stylistically inappropriate here.

...a typical context being Violent crime increased by 10% last year. Meanwhile, the government didn't even increase spending on the police by enough to offset inflation. But stylistic choices at this level are hardly relevant to the average learner.

I think the argument could be advanced for the violent crime/government inaction example that the meaning is "And yet even while this was happening...."  There is still a context of something ongoing. It is not purely "but" or  "however" without any reference to unfolding or ongoing events.

@FumbleFingers - I do agree with your examples, and the particular spin you put on the sound of the word.  Regarding the education expenditure, I did not in the slightest read them as real countries; I read it as "X spends 15 and Y spends 14 - meanwhile, the rest spend a pittance, and they wonder why they are illiterate."  Exactly as you ay its' a smarmy (shmarmy?) way to put a serious issue.

@TimR I'm afraid I disagree, (a) things do happen "in the spacetime continuum"; it's hard to think of examples where it would be wholly without that meaning; (b) as I, well, asserted, it's constantly and normally used even where to some extent that is illogical "We have smartphones and supercomputers and our roads are falling apart and bridges collapse every time a ship passes, meanwhile the bloody Roman Empire doesn't even have decimal digits and their roads are flawless!" it makes perfect sense and it's what you'd say - I'm running a movie for you of the two for comparison, and there it is

(After all, we commonly say, for example, "and on the other hand the Romans have flawless roads and plumbing ..." it is not of course on or in my hand, nor is it even something that sensibly could be in a hand (it's a "period of history and/or socio-economic sphere"). But I'm telling two stories for you, over here (I gesture my left hand) we have blah blah California blah, meanwhile over here (I gesture my right hand) we have the Romans blah blah ...

GRAMMATICALLY, linguistically, and logically, "meanwhile" is perfectly valid here. If you don't like some subtle implication, that's not a language question but a diplomacy question. But in any case, in the absence of larger context, I don't see how you can assume that "meanwhile" means "... and that's why they're illiterate boobs". It could just as well mean "wow these folks spend way more than others to get the same result, how inefficient". Or "these countries face particular challenges that make education more expensive". Or probably other interpretations.

@FumbleFingers I'm pretty sure I've seen "meanwhile" used in essentially the exact same way as the asker's example in major news sources. It wouldn't be my first choice for the situation either, but it seems to be the choice of some professional writers. My view is that both answers are true: there's nothing really wrong with "meanwhile" in this context, and your answer provides some reasons why a person might say it's not the best word to use in this context. It's not objectively wrong, but it is subjectively wrong.

@ToddWilcox: I'm pretty sure almost every native speaker has seen "meanwhile" used in essentially the exact same way. I never said it's syntactically incorrect, and I don't think anyone else did either. It's entirely an Off Topic matter of preferred stylistic choice. As a native Anglophone with a degree in English Language & Literature, I obviously tend to rate my preference higher than the average, but that's tempered by a lifelong interest in "descriptive linguistics" as opposed to "prescriptive grammar". I just don't want to promote "stylistically weak" usages among learners.

@Jay: I think you miss the point (or maybe there are several points being made here, and mine is the only one you're missing! :) It's not relevant what "contrast" is being implied by meanwhile. The point is a contrast is being drawn in a context where that almost certainly amounts to the writer expressing an opinion, whereas the remit is simply to provide a description. So far as I can tell. But we haven't been shown the actual chart to be described, nor have we seen the exact text requesting that a description be written.

I agree wih @FumbleFingers "Meanwhile" is being used to establish a contrast here. "Sure, there's these guys, but look at this guy!" That's something that you want to do in some contexts (eg a narrative in a newspaper article) but not others (simple scene description). eg you might say "GDP rose in China, ballooned in India, and soared in Nepal. Meanwhile, Thailand's GDP fell". But not "In the forest there were macaques and lemurs in the trees. Meanwhile, there were frogs in the pond". The editor is just saying to the OP that "your situation is more like the first situation than the second".

@dan I wouldn't find it at all surprising or confusing if someone said, "I heard lemurs in the trees. Meanwhile, frogs were croaking in the pond." In the example we're beating to death here, yes, there's a contrast. Maybe if we read the larger context we'd see that the writer is making a value judgement. But pointing out that two numbers are different does not of itself imply that one is a problem that the writer is condemning.

Your use of the word "meanwhile" is certainly not incorrect. To a native English speaker, it might just feel a little out of place in your sentence. Since there doesn't seem to be a consensus on this page as to exactly why, I'll add my opinion: "meanwhile" is often used to signal a change of topic, which isn't what you're doing here. When you say

"(sentence 1). Meanwhile, (sentence 2)."

The reader instinctively thinks that you're done talking about the context of sentence 1 for a while. In your case, both sentences are contributing (I assume) to the same idea and are closely related. The reader feels a little jarred because you hinted at a transition that never came.
One other thing to note: it is very common to hear advice along the lines of "Your sentence still makes sense if you remove (some word or phrase), therefore you should remove it". In some settings where conciseness is key, it might really be worthwhile to trim out everything that isn't strictly necessary. But often you have a little more freedom, even in moderately formal writing. Don't be afraid of adding the occasional word just for flavor and style.

Other answers give lots of details, but an important high-level point that should be said clearly: From an ELL point of view, your use of meanwhile is absolutely fine!  Your example is completely natural and idiomatic — out of context, I wouldn’t suspect it was from a non-native speaker.  Any objections to meanwhile here are just at the level of style, not linguistic correctness.  As other answers explain, it’s arguably not a good stylistic choice — it’s a commonly overused filler word, and can sometimes be ambiguous or misleading.

The term "meanwhile" is generally used with "action" verbs.  The sentence could sensibly read, e.g.

India spent 15% on education--the highest of any country--while Thailand spent 13%.  Meanwhile, other countries spent an average of around 7%.

While there might be some constructs where "meanwhile" could be used with linking verbs, it's far more often used with action verbs.  Even if things aren't changing, saying "Meanwhile, the temperature outside remained above 40C" would read much more naturally than "Meanwhile, the temperature outside was above 40C".

I wouldn't actually say it's inadvisable. As others have said, it's mostly a filler word, which might easily be deleted:

Education expenditure was highest in India at 15%, followed by 13% in
Thailand. The figures for the remaining countries were
around 7%.

"Meanwhile" carries a very slight implication of "In contrast" which is probably what I'd use if I meant to contrast two countries with high percentages against the rest of the group.

All these answers and not one contains a single reference to a dictionary. The adverb in the OP's sentence is perfectly acceptable. The error lies in the interpretation of its meaning, in the OP's example it is not "at the same time" rather its meaning is used to contrast two situations,  comparable to "on the other hand".
Oxford Learners Dictionary

3. used to compare two aspects of a situation
Stress can be extremely damaging to your health. Exercise, meanwhile, can reduce its effects.

Collins Dictionary

3. ADVERB
You use meanwhile to introduce a different aspect of a particular situation, especially one that is completely opposite to the one previously mentioned.

Almost four million households are in debt to their energy company. Meanwhile, suppliers' profits have doubled.


Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English

3. used to compare two things, especially if they are completely different and are happening at the same time

The incomes of male professionals went up by almost 80%. Meanwhile, part-time women workers saw their earnings fall.


Wiktionary

3. In contrast to aspects previously mentioned.
Synonyms: at the same time, on the other hand

Some songs on the album are beautiful. Meanwhile, others are quite forgettable.


Oxford English Dictionary
(Unfortunately, the rest of the entry is behind a paywall)

1597– meanwhile, n. & adv.
In adversative or concessive use: nevertheless, still; on the other hand. Cf. sense A.1b.


one more thing... it's usually at the same specific time
I feel like the other answers have only hinted at this, so let me add that
the reason it is out of place is that it

typically refers to the same, specific, small period of time,
where that connection is meaningful to those involved
and brings some tension to the reader.

A broad range like a year or a fiscal quarter is not where "meanwhile" is used.
It's more like
"Person A was hurrying to complete their task.
Meanwhile, Person B [at the exact same moment]  was trying to prevent them from succeeding"
